# How to export mysql databases with different ENGINE?

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, myisam, mysql-cluster, storage-engine

I'm setting up MySQL Cluster. As it uses `ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER`, how could I export my databases from MySQL Server specifying the ENGINE?

Is there a way to do this?

All my tables are `MYISAM`

Comment: WHat do you want to achieve? If convert table from MyISAM to NDB - `ALTER TABLE comments ENGINE=ndb;`

Comment: I want to export them with `ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER` not with `ENGINE=MYISAM`... I'm not able to do that wile the database is now in production.

Comment: Do conventional mysqldump and then convert engine=myisam to engine=ndbcluster using sed. Or even text editor with search/replace may suffice.

Comment: The thing is that my `.sql` file is about 50 GB, this could be a problem right? :S

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create two mysqldumps

- Schema Only, No Data
- Data Only, No Schema

Using [**sed**](http://linux.about.com/od/commands/l/blcmdl1_sed.htm), mysqldump all databases except `information_schema`, `mysql`, `performance_schema`

Create a script with the following commands

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"

SQL="SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name) FROM information_schema.schemata"
SQL="${SQL} WHERE schema_name NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
DB_CSV=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"`
DBLIST=`echo "${DB_CSV}" | sed 's/,/ /g'`
#
# Schema Only, No Data
#
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} -d -B ${DBLIST}|sed 's/ENGINE=MyISAM/ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER' > schema_only.sql
#
# Data Only, No Schema
#
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} -t -B ${DBLIST} > data_only.sql
```

Run this script. You should have two files

- `schema_only.sql`

  - Should have all the `CREATE TABLE` commands
  - Should have no data
  - All `ENGINE=MyISAM` will now say `ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER`
- `data_only.sql` : All the INSERTs to reload the tables

Run the schema_only.sql` script in the MySQL NDB Cluster setup.

Check to make sure every table was created.

Make sure there are now special options prevent the table creation, such as

- FULLTEXT indexes
- ROW_FORMAT option

If something went wrong, you can always hand edit `schema_only.sql` and reload it.

Once every table is in place, run `data_only.sql` in the MySQL NDB Cluster.

## Give it a Try !!!