# MySQL Command to Mass Change Specific DB from MyISAM to InnoDB and vice versa?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, command-line

I have an mu WordPress database and I want to change it from MyISAM to InnoDB to test its performance.

Which MySQL command/commands will do it for all of the tables instead of doing manually one by one?

Is there anything that I should keep my eye on in this application?

Comment: Here are some subtle differences to watch for:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods to mass convert all your MyISAM data into InnoDB

## CONVERSION METHOD #1 : In-Place Conversion

You can run `ALTER TABLE tblname ENGINE=InnoDB;` against all MyISAM tables

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;" > /tmp/Mass_Convert_MyISAM_To_InnoDB.sql
SQL="${SQL} SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=InnoDB;')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM'"
SQL="${SQL} AND table_schema NOT IN"
SQL="${SQL} ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN-e"${SQL}" > /tmp/Mass_Convert_MyISAM_To_InnoDB.sql
less /tmp/Mass_Convert_MyISAM_To_InnoDB.sql
```

If you are satisfied with the script's contents, then run it

```
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} < /tmp/Mass_Convert_MyISAM_To_InnoDB.sql
```

I wrote a similar script 3 years ago : [When to switch from MyISAM to InnoDB?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/22678/when-to-switch-from-myisam-to-innodb/22680#22680)

## CONVERSION METHOD #2 : Dump and Reload

[Verace's answer is short and sweet](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/119016/877).

Here is the way to do it

```
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
#
# Gather all Databases except MySQL-centric Databases
#
SQL="SET group_concat_max_len = 1048576;"
SQL="${SQL} SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(schema_name SEPARATOR ' ')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.schemata WHERE schema_name"
SQL=${SQL} NOT IN ('information_schema','mysql','performance_schema')"
DBLIST=`mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -ANe"${SQL}"`
#
# Dump the Schema Only, changing the Storage Engine on the Fly
#
DUMP_OPTS="--single-transaction --routines --triggers -d --add-drop-database -B ${DBLIST}"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${DUMP_OPTS} | sed 's/ENGINE=MyISAM/ENGINE=InnoDB/g' > Schema.sql
#
# Dump the Data Only
#
DUMP_OPTS="-t -B ${DBLIST}"
mysqldump ${MYSQL_CONN} ${DUMP_OPTS} > Data.sql
```

Then, you run the two scripts

```
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} < Schema.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} < Data.sql
```

I wrote a similar answer last year : [How to export mysql databases with different ENGINE?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/77665/how-to-export-mysql-databases-with-different-engine/77681#77681)

**NOTE : If you want to convert just one database, here is the in-place method**

```
DB_TO_COVERT=mydata
MYSQL_USER=root
MYSQL_PASS=rootpassword
MYSQL_CONN="-u${MYSQL_USER} -p${MYSQL_PASS}"
echo "SET SQL_LOG_BIN = 0;" > /tmp/Mass_Convert_MyISAM_To_InnoDB.sql
SQL="${SQL} SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE ',table_schema,'.',table_name,' ENGINE=InnoDB;')"
SQL="${SQL} FROM information_schema.tables WHERE engine='MyISAM'"
SQL="${SQL} AND table_schema = '${DB_TO_COVERT}'"
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} -AN-e"${SQL}" > /tmp/Mass_Convert_MyISAM_To_InnoDB.sql
mysql ${MYSQL_CONN} < /tmp/Mass_Convert_MyISAM_To_InnoDB.sql
```

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: I tried the last one method and I got this msg: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DB_TO_COVERT=xxxxx MYSQL_USER=root MYSQL_PASS=xxxxx' at line 1. My SQL Version is 5.5.46-cll.

Answer (score 0):

Do a mysqldump and then use your editor of choice to search for the word ENGINE - change MyISAM to InnoDB (for all tables in your database - and NOT the system tables) and reload your database. Your db will now run with all tables as InnoDB.